# What is the difference between the System.Web.Mvc Namespace and the System.Web.Routing Namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I have noticed that in ASP.NET there are two namespaces which I would have expected to be under the same namespace:

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing

Upon researching this I found a third namespace:

- System.Web.Mvc.Routing

Even with all the research I have done, I can't for the life of me work out why there are 3 namespaces, all of which by the looks of things relate to the ASP.NET MVC Framework.

I would have imagined that it is possibly a case of a namespace being deprecated, etc, but I can't find any information on this being the case.

I would appreciate it if it could be explained to me why there are three namespaces opposed to one, and the justification on why the namespace is separate opposed to just being part of one encapsulating namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing can be used outside of the MVC framework, such as in [WebForms](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx)

I *think* MS duplicated MVC Routing into System.Web.Routing  to make the lack of dependency on MVC more explicit - but kept the old namespace for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I wasn't aware that routing could be used without an MVC framework.